# Dynamic CSS File in WordPress

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I've created a theme options panel which works fine. My issue is that I can't use `get_option()` within in a css file.

I'm loading this into the head

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<?php bloginfo( 'template_url' ); ?>/lib/display/dynamic-css.php" />
```

i've set `header('Content-type: text/css');` to the dynamic-css.php file but there is know what to use the options set.

Anyone have a solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line to your dynamic CSS file:

```
require_once('../../../../wp-load.php');
```

The path might need to be changed, the file is in the main WP directory.